# Find a specific word(diagonally) in 2D matrix

Tags: java, arrays

"Given a 2D char array and a string.

find if the specific string appears diagonally in the matrix".

```
private static boolean diagonalContains(char[][] grid,String word){
    int wordLength = word.length();
    char[] wordArray = word.toCharArray();
    for(int i =0, length = grid.length; i < length; i++){
        loop:for(int j =0, k = i, subLength = grid[i].length;
                j < subLength && k >= wordLength; j++, k--){
            for(int l =0; l < wordLength; l++){
                if(grid[j + l][k - l]!= wordArray[l]){
                    continue loop;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The function asks me to return value, although I did, thus I am not able to run the code. I've tried to put return statement in different regions of the code but none seems to be working.
Plus I would like to know if the code is efficient for the purpose of the exercise?

Comment: Any exceptions or error messages? If yes, where... Please post the stack trace or a compiler message!

Comment: Think about what happens when your method does not find the string anywhere.
The code will finish all loops until the end of the method,
but it does not know which value to return.
You need to add a `return` statement there, too.

Comment: I guess it should not compile with "loop:for"

Comment: @torina Actually `loop:` is OK. It is a label, which is used later on by `continue loop`. May be you didn't use labels yet, because they are considered bad practice.

Comment: Try this `private static boolean diagonalContains(char[][] grid, String word) {
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0, length = grid.length; i < length; i++) {
            s = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                s += grid[i][j];
            }
            if (s.contains(word))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }`

Comment: @HadiJ It could help if you can add this as answer. other wise it is hard to read this kind of code :)

Comment: Define `diagonally` : any diagonal ? any direction ? or just main diagonal from top (0,0) to bottom (i,j) ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there are two problems
1. Every function should return some value, if the return type is not void. In your case, a return value is specified only if the criteria is satisfied. You are supposed to return false, otherwise.

```
  private static boolean diagonalContains(char[][] grid,String word){
    int wordLength = word.length();
    char[] wordArray = word.toCharArray();
    for(int i =0, length = grid.length; i < length; i++){
      loop:for(int j =0, k = i, subLength = grid[i].length;
      j < subLength && k >= wordLength; j++, k--){
        for(int l =0; l < wordLength; l++){
          if(grid[j + l][k - l]!= wordArray[l]){
            continue loop;
          }
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

2. The code seems to be inefficient and the logic seems to be wrong. So try the following code.

```
    import java.util.*;
    class WordDiagonal{
      public static void main(String[] args){

        char grid[][] = {{'a','b','c'},{'d','e','f'},{'g','h','i'}};

        if(checkDiagonalSubstring(grid,"aei")){
          System.out.println("Contains..");
        }else{
          System.out.println("Sorry..!");

        }

      }


      private static boolean checkDiagonalSubstring(char[][] grid, String word){

        String diagonalString = "";
        Integer i = 0;

        for(char[] charArray : grid){
          diagonalString += charArray[i++];
        }

        if(diagonalString.contains(word)){
          return true;
        }

        return false;
      }

    }
```